# Android Studio. Twitter SDK integration

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried to integrate Twitter SDK to my android-application. According official documentation (http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/twitter.html) I've added to build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

But I've got error in Android Studio:
**Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.0**

Could you please help me with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be due to some of the other stuff Fabric.io requires to work.

I recommend you plug in their Android Studio IDE plugin, as it handles everything pretty seamlessly! https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

According to this, have you updated your gradle file to include:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
    // react quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Not sure if you need ALL of it, but you probably need some of it. I needed to add these when using Crashlytics, because Twitter hosts some of their own repos.